# Find a number of a file in a range of numbers of another file

Tags: bash, perl, awk

I have this two input files:

```
file1
1   982444
1   46658343
3   15498261
2   238295146
21  47423507
X   110961739
17  7490379
13  31850803
13  31850989

file2
1   982400  982480
1   46658345    46658350
2   14  109
2   5000    9000
2   238295000   238295560
X   110961739   120000000
17  7490200 8900005
```

And this is my desired output:

```
Desired output:
1   982444
2   238295146
X   110961739
17  7490379
```

This is what I want: Find the column 1 element of file1 in column 1 of file2. If the number is the same, take the number of column 2 of file1 and check if it is included in the range of numbers of column2 and 3 of file2. If it is included, print the line of file1 in the output.

Maybe is a little confusing to understand, but I'm doing my best. I have tried some things but I'm far away from the solution and any help will be really appreciated. In bash, awk or perl please.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just using `awk`. The solution doesn't loop through `file1` repeatedly.

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
NR == FNR {
    # I'm processing file2 since NR still matches FNR
    # I'd store the ranges from it on a[] and b[]
    # x[] acts as a counter to the number of range pairs stored that's specific to $1
    i = ++x[$1]
    a[$1, i] = $2
    b[$1, i] = $3
    # Skip to next record; Do not allow the next block to process a record from file2.
    next
}
{
    # I'm processing file1 since NR is already greater than FNR
    # Let's get the index for the last range first then go down until we reach 0.
    # Nothing would happen as well if i evaluates to nothing i.e. $1 doesn't have a range for it.
    for (i = x[$1]; i; --i) {
        if ($2 >= a[$1, i] && $2 <= b[$1, i]) {
            # I find that $2 is within range. Now print it.
            print
            # We're done so let's skip to the next record.
            next
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
awk -f script.awk file2 file1
```

Output:

```
1   982444
2   238295146
X   110961739
17  7490379
```

A similar approach using Bash (version 4.0 or newer):

```
#!/bin/bash

FILE1=$1 FILE2=$2

declare -A A B X

while read F1 F2 F3; do
    (( I = ++X[$F1] ))
    A["$F1|$I"]=$F2
    B["$F1|$I"]=$F3
done < "$FILE2"

while read -r LINE; do
    read F1 F2 <<< "$LINE"
    for (( I = X[$F1]; I; --I )); do
        if (( F2 >= A["$F1|$I"] && F2 <= B["$F1|$I"] )); then
            echo "$LINE"
            continue
        fi
    done
done < "$FILE1"
```

Usage:

```
bash script.sh file1 file2
```

Comment: Oh, I think this is the correct answer, because @fedorqui, for your solution I get repeated lines in ouput (don't know why).

Comment: Could you explain a little bit the code please? Just for learning... thanks!

Comment: @cucurbit In the first block `NR == FNR { ...`, the code would allocate the ranges in a and b. . In a way they get stored like two-dimensional arrays. This only processes file 2 since it is only in the first file processed where NR and FNR matches. The next block is the part where file 1 is processed. It simply walks through the ranges and compares the currect record. If it matches, it prints and skips to next record with `next`.

Comment: @cucurbit repeated lines? Please update your question with proper sample input and desired output, as with the current one it is working fine.

Comment: @fedorqui He probably refers to ranges that intersects and would cause repeated printing if a line matches on both. It happens when file1 is read repeatedly.

Comment: @cucurbit I added the comments. I hope it helps you.

Comment: @konsolebox oh I see. Well, you took good care of this case, so I am not going to update my answer to cover that. Good one.

Comment: +1 - the awk solution is the correct answer. I wouldn't even consider using bash for this, it's just text processing which is what awk was designed to do and does best.

Comment: @cucurbit note that this is the answer you ended up using, you'd better accept it instead of mine, to make it clear.

Answer (score 2):

Let's mix bash and awk:

```
while read col min max
do
    awk -v col=$col -v min=$min -v max=$max '$1==col && min<=$2 && $2<=max' f1
done < f2
```

#### Explanation

- For each line of file2, read the min and the max, together with the value of the first column.
- Given these values, check in file1 for those lines having same first column and being 2nd column in the range specified by file 2.

#### Test

```
$ while read col min max; do awk -v col=$col -v min=$min -v max=$max '$1==col && min<=$2 && $2<=max' f1; done < f2
1   982444
2   238295146
X   110961739
17  7490379
```

Comment: Thanks @fedorqui but "1   46658343" should not be there..."46658343" is not between "46658345" and "46658350", :S

Comment: Sorry @hek2mgl , it's a bit difficult to explain. I want the lines of file1, that are included in the range of numbers of col2 and col3 of file2, IF col1 and col1 of both files are the same.

Comment: @cucurbit Oh I see... testing with `awk 'FNR==NR {b[$1]=$2; c[$1]=$3; next} $1 in b && b[$1]<=$2 && $2<=c[$1]' f2 f1` but still it is giving problems because 1st column with `1` appears twice.

Comment: @cucurbit It's ok, I got it with your last comment.. (therefore deleted my)

Comment: @fedorqui Yes... in the original file1, I have the col1 numbers repeated a lot of times. The thing is, you take the line1 of file1, take col1 of line1, compare with col1 of file2, if they are equal, check the range, if not, pass to the next line of file2 and check again. If there is a line of file2 in which the line of file1 is included, print line of file1 and pass to the next line of file1. I think that I need several loops... but I'm a bit lost!

Comment: nice one @fedorqui +1

Comment: Works great! Thanks a lot, and for the comments also! :)

Answer (score 0):

Pure bash , **based on Fedorqui solution**:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read col_2 min max
do
    while read col_1 val
    do
       (( col_1 == col_2 && ( min <= val && val <= max ) )) && echo $col_1 $val
    done < file1
done < file2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cut -d' ' -f1 input2 | sed 's/^/^/;s/$/\\s/' | \ 
    grep -f - <(cat input2 input1) | sort -n -k1 -k3 | \ 
    awk 'NF==3 { 
            split(a,b,","); 
            for (v in b) 
                if ($2 <= b[v] && $3 >= b[v]) 
                    print $1, b[v]; 
                if ($1 != p) a=""} 
         NF==2 {p=$1;a=a","$2}'
```

*Produces:*

```
X 110961739
1 982444
2 238295146
17 7490379
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Perl solution. It could be much faster but less concise if I built a hash out of `file2`, but this should be fine.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my @bounds = do {
  open my $fh, '<', 'file2';
  map [ split ], <$fh>;
};

open my $fh, '<', 'file1';
while (my $line = <$fh>) {
  my ($key, $val) = split ' ', $line;
  for my $bound (@bounds) {
    next unless $key eq $bound->[0] and $val >= $bound->[1] and $val <= $bound->[2];
    print $line;
    last;
  }
}
```

**output**

```
1   982444
2   238295146
X   110961739
17  7490379
```